# How can read main document id value of collectiongroup in firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

My question need to explain here
[image]

in photo , you will see current user id is ```

oUkU2BHhT3M27ld3AwHPGn6nU9q2 ```

its id is also in swipes collection group.
I query current user id from all swipes collection as follow

```
     const queryid =query(collectionGroup(db, "swipes"),where("id","==",user.uid))
     const myid = await getDocs(queryid)
     .then((snapshot)=>snapshot.docs.map(doc=>doc.id))
     console.log('myid ',myid)
```

But MY problem is I dont know how can get id value if this swipes collection groups
I mean I want to know all owner id of swipes collection that contain current user id

Please help me

In this case , I want to read ```

HPYzRaCakGbS0lu9IhMq94dK0rj2 ```
because this id swipes collection contain current user id
I want to read all owner id of swipes collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine the parent document for a result in a collection group query, you can do:

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(queryid)
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  const parentCollection = doc.ref.parent
  const parentDocRef = parentCollection.parent
  const parentDocId = parentDocRef.id
  ...
})
```

Comment: it is not work ,``` const queryid =query(collectionGroup(db, "swipes"),where("id","==",user.uid))
     const querySnapshot = await getDocs(queryid)
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  const parentCollection = doc.ref.parent
  const parentDocRef = parentCollection.parent
  const parentDocId = parentDocRef.Id
  console.log(parentDocRef)
})```.final result is undefine

Comment: Does the code I shared make sense to you? If so, did you step through the code in a debugger already? If so, does any of the lines give a meaningful value? Which is the first line that doesn't have an expected value?

Comment: sorry ,I get the id value by this way .then((snapshot)=>snapshot.docs.map(doc=>doc.ref.parent.parent.id))